# How to style facebook like button?

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, styling

I am trying to apply css to facebook like button. I know that it is violating TOS to change how the like button look. All I am trying to do is  change the background of facebook like button to make it consistence with my website.

I googled about it and found several articles that I can style facebook like button if I am using fbml because fbml does not use iframe. The problem is, it looks like facebook is using iframe for fbml as well.

as far as I know, I can't directly style a webpage that is included in an iframe.

Is there an api for styling (in my case, changing background only!!) the like button?

Comment: Apart from the fact it is against the TOS, I'd be willing to bet it will also make users less likely to click it. The facebook colours are a brand, why change that to suit your webpage?

Comment: why do you want to violate the TnC of Facebook? You can build your custom like button and link it with facebook's like button's click event.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use dark or light theme.

You can not do anything to an `iframe` of whom's `src` attribute is not your domain.

The only thing I can think of is an ugly hack using absolute positioning, opacity and z-index, but I don't think it is worth mentioning.

Answer (score 0):

how about over riding the image with another? i know its not the best practice, but u can't change the Facebook branded "Like" button