# Can't style FB like button

Tags: css, facebook

I've been trying to follow all the advice I found here, but I just can't seem to style the Facebook like button. Here's the website: http://www.threespringsranch.com/

At this point I'm just trying to stop the comment box from coming up as the easiest solution to the problem. I've tried the obvious of adding .fb_edge_comment_widget {display: none !important;} to my css, but it just won't read it. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks,
Brian

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to style facebook like button?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5385700/how-to-style-facebook-like-button)

Answer (score 4):

the short answer is that it's not possible to style the FB like button. It's in an iframe and you have no real access to the style in there.

More than that, Facebook policy forbid you from modifying their widget look and feel.

> d. You must not obscure or cover elements of our social plugins, such
>   as the Like button or Like box plugin.

[From Facebook policy](https://developers.facebook.com/policy/)

And, if you don't care about the warning, well you can "hide" the comment pop-up of the like button by wrapping it into an element (`div` or `span`), setting size on this wrapper and add the `overflow: hidden` CSS prop. This will somewhat work, but it's going to be unmaintainable if you have to manage internationalization as like button will change size.

So, the best, don't modify it, else, you have a little hack.

Comment: Thanks Simon. The overflow:hidden worked. It's not ideal, but it works!