# how to isolate CSS in a website gadget?

Tags: jquery, css

I have a livescore website and I am trying to make a gadget of that website to show part of it in others websites,the problem that I face is how to isolate my code (JavaScript and CSS) from the code of the host site for my gadget.
I use an "anonymous function" like this:

```
(function() {

// Localize jQuery variable
var jQuery;

/******** Load jQuery if not present *********/
if (window.jQuery === undefined || window.jQuery.fn.jquery !== '1.8.3') {
    var script_tag = document.createElement('script');
    script_tag.setAttribute("type","text/javascript");
    script_tag.setAttribute("src",
        "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js");
    if (script_tag.readyState) {
      script_tag.onreadystatechange = function () { // For old versions of IE
          if (this.readyState == 'complete' || this.readyState == 'loaded') {
              scriptLoadHandler();
          }
      };
    } else { // Other browsers
      script_tag.onload = scriptLoadHandler;
    }
    // Try to find the head, otherwise default to the documentElement
    (document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0] || document.documentElement).appendChild(script_tag);
} else {
    // The jQuery version on the window is the one we want to use
    jQuery = window.jQuery;
    main();
}

/******** Called once jQuery has loaded ******/
function scriptLoadHandler() {
    // Restore $ and window.jQuery to their previous values and store the
    // new jQuery in our local jQuery variable
    jQuery = window.jQuery.noConflict(true);
    // Call our main function
    main(); 
}

/******** Our main function ********/
function main() { 
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    /******* Load CSS *******/
    var css_link = $("<link>", { 
            rel: "stylesheet", 
            type: "text/css", 
            href: "http://localhost/aaa/widget/widget.css" 
        });
        css_link.appendTo('head');          
        var txt;
        txt='<div id="wrapper">';
        txt=txt+'<ul class="tabs">';
        txt=txt+'<li id="fixtures_tab"><a href="#fixtures">All</a></li>';
        txt=txt+'<li id="live_tab"><a href="#live">Live</a></li>';
        txt=txt+'<li id="finished_tab"><a href="#finished">finished</a></li>';
        txt=txt+'<li id="program_tab"><a href="#program">Program</a></li>';
        txt=txt+'<li id="postpond_tab"><a href="#postpond">Postpond</a></li>';
        txt=txt+'<li id="selected_tab"><a id="f" href="#fav">Selected (0)</a></li>';
        txt=txt+'</ul>';
        txt=txt+'<div class="tab-container">';
        txt=txt+'<div id="fixtures" class="tab-content"><script type="text/javascript">get_All_Today_Matches();</script></div>';
        txt=txt+'<div id="live" class="tab-content"><script type="text/javascript"></script></div>';
        txt=txt+'<div id="finished" class="tab-content"><script type="text/javascript"></script></div>';
        txt=txt+'<div id="program" class="tab-content"><script type="text/javascript"></script></div>';
        txt=txt+'<div id="postpond" class="tab-content"><script type="text/javascript"></script></div>';
        txt=txt+'<div id="fav" class="tab-content"><script type="text/javascript"></script></div>';
        txt=txt+'</div>';
        txt=txt+'</div>';
        $('#widget-container').html(txt);
    });
}

})(); // We call our anonymous function immediately
```

everything is going fine for the JQuery but not for CSS (the CSS file is loaded and worked fine but some of the hosting site CSS is effecting my CSS) I have no control on the hosting site CSS and I think that I have isolated my code well by using anonymous function but why is my CSS affected by the website orginal CSS ??? help me please i have been at this point for a while

Comment: You need to reset any styles you think they may have set. For example, if they had `div{background:#FF0000}` then all your divs will have red backgrounds. You can revert it by setting transparent or inherit. A good way to start is `.mycontainer *{font:inherit;(etc)}`

Comment: I tried to use CSS reset but i am afraid it is useless it still the same problem. I used also !important but no response. my problem specially in the fonts sizes and families

Answer (score 2):

I know of two possible solutions.

One is to have your code embedded on the other site via an [`iframe`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/iframe). Your CSS won't clash then, unless the other site [specifically writes something](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14619364/apply-css-to-iframe-content) to modify your CSS inside the iframe. But by default, it won't be  a problem.

Otherwise, you'll have to add `MyWidget_` to the beginning of all of your class/ID names so as to prevent collision with the other site.

Comment: I agree completely, this is about the only way, but also like Arun said I'd remove any ids and opt for class names to be able to use multiple instances of widgets.

Answer (score 0):

my solution will be is to add a class `my-widget-wrapper` to the top element, in this case I think it is the element with id `wrapper`.

Then specify all css rules in my style file as a child of the class `my-widget-wrapper`.

Ex: To change the color of `a` elements to green, instead of css rule

```
a {
    color: green;
}
```

I would use

```
.my-widget-wrapper a {
    color: green
}
```

*Side Note*: When you develop a widget never use fixed id's in the widget elements, since it will restrict you to have only one instance of the widget in the page. Instead of using `id` attribute to identify elements use custom `class` attributes

Comment: i use classes in the css file the id in the wrapper is just for jquery. inside the jquery i add some html and make the style of them using widget.css so the id wrapper has nothing to do wwith the css