# can I use my own icon for a facebook plugin?

Tags: html, facebook, plugins

I'm using a wrapbootstrap template (https://wrapbootstrap.com/theme/any-day-now-responsive-theme-WB05535B4) that has specific icons for various social plugins.  I'd like to use the default for facebook (and the rest).

Here is the code for the facebook "Like" plugin, taken from the facebook site (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/web/#plugins):

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>My Great Web page</title>
</head>
<body>
   <iframe src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=YOUR_URL"
    scrolling="no" frameborder="0"
    style="border:none; width:450px; height:80px"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

Is there anyway to use a different icon?  Will facebook frown upon this?

Comment: [You can't](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5385700/how-to-style-facebook-like-button)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have actually attempted this before on my own website but came up with nothing.
Because the source is specifically defined I don't believe their is ever a way to :(
I do however think that they would frown upon a hackers success!